# handling submit in a jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a page using jquery tabs.  In one tab, there is a form (included using href="" attribute in tabs).  I can't seem to intercept the form submission.  When I open the file which contains the form directly, I use

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
  }
```

to stop submission.  This works when I load the file directly but fails inside the tab.  [I've also tried $("form").on('submit',...) which fails as well.]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the deferred form of 'on' worked.  In this case

```
$("form").on('click',"input[name='registration']",function(e) {
```

allowed me to trap the event and preventDefault if appropriate.